# string.IsNullOrEmpty(string) vs. string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is use of `string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)` when checking a string considered as bad practice when there is `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)` in .NET 4.0 and above?

Answer (score 367, accepted):

The best practice is selecting the most appropriate one.

> .Net Framework 4.0 Beta 2 has a new IsNullOrWhiteSpace() method for
>   strings which generalizes the IsNullOrEmpty() method to also include other white
>   space besides empty string.
>
> **The term “white space” includes all characters that are not visible on
>   screen. For example, space, line break, tab and empty string are white
>   space characters***.

Reference : [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/10/25/net-framework-4-0-string-isnullorwhitespace-method.aspx)

> For performance, IsNullOrWhiteSpace is not ideal but is
>   good. The method calls will result in a small performance penalty.
>   Further, the IsWhiteSpace method itself has some indirections that can
>   be removed if you are not using Unicode data. As always, premature
>   optimization may be evil, but it is also fun.

Reference : [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/isnullorwhitespace)

**Check the source code** (Reference Source .NET Framework 4.6.2)

[IsNullorEmpty](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,23a8597f842071f4)

```
[Pure]
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(String value) {
    return (value == null || value.Length == 0);
}
```

[IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55e241b6143365ef)

```
[Pure]
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
    if (value == null) return true;

    for(int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
        if(!Char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Examples**

```
string nullString = null;
string emptyString = "";
string whitespaceString = "    ";
string nonEmptyString = "abc123";

bool result;

result = String.IsNullOrEmpty(nullString);            // true
result = String.IsNullOrEmpty(emptyString);           // true
result = String.IsNullOrEmpty(whitespaceString);      // false
result = String.IsNullOrEmpty(nonEmptyString);        // false

result = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nullString);       // true
result = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emptyString);      // true
result = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(whitespaceString); // true
result = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nonEmptyString);   // false
```

Comment: Now I'm confused: "IsNullOrWhiteSpace is a convenience method that is similar to the following code, except that it offers superior performance" from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rob The code in question is `return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0;`, which involves new string allocation and two separate checks. Most probably inside IsNullOrWhitespace it is done via single pass without any allocations by checking that each char in the string is the whitespace, hence superior performance. What confuses you actually?

Comment: Thanks! I never knew if ```IsNullOrWhitespace()``` would match an empty string. In essence ```IsNullOrEmpty()``` matches a subset of ```IsNullOrWhitespace()```.

Answer (score 171):

The differences in practice :

```
string testString = "";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("IsNullOrEmpty : {0}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(testString)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("IsNullOrWhiteSpace : {0}", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testString)));
Console.ReadKey();

Result :
IsNullOrEmpty : True
IsNullOrWhiteSpace : True

**************************************************************
string testString = " MDS   ";

IsNullOrEmpty : False
IsNullOrWhiteSpace : False

**************************************************************
string testString = "   ";

IsNullOrEmpty : False
IsNullOrWhiteSpace : True

**************************************************************
string testString = string.Empty;

IsNullOrEmpty : True
IsNullOrWhiteSpace : True

**************************************************************
string testString = null;

IsNullOrEmpty : True
IsNullOrWhiteSpace : True
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Makes more sense than the accepted answer with showing actual examples rather than a redirect.

Comment: @eaglei22 The accepted answer answers the question. This doesn't.

Comment: @JimBalter 7yrs later, I can see your point.

Answer (score 39):

They are different functions. You should decide for your situation what do you need.

I don't consider using any of them as a bad practice. Most of the time `IsNullOrEmpty()` is enough. But you have the choice :)

Comment: For example, a user name field on a registration page would use IsNullOrEmtpy to validate so a user couldn't have a space as their name.

Comment: @Rfvgyhn: if you want to check that username doesn't have spaces _anywhere_ - you should use `Contains`. If you want to ensure that username can't consist of spaces _only_ - `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is ok. `IsNullOrEmpty` ensures only that username was entered somehow.

Comment: Indeed. I was just trying to give a concrete example to add to your answer. In the real world, a user name validation rule would usually contain a bit more logic than just checking if its empty or whitespace.

Comment: Upvoted for actually answering the question, unlike so many of the "answers" here.

Comment: @Chris As Ivan pointed out, your "concrete example" is simply wrong -- `!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)` doesn't prevent names from containing spaces.

Answer (score 28):

Here is the actual implementation of both methods ( decompiled using dotPeek)

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string value)
    {
      if (value != null)
        return value.Length == 0;
      else
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the <paramref name="value"/> parameter is null or <see cref="F:System.String.Empty"/>, or if <paramref name="value"/> consists exclusively of white-space characters.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="value">The string to test.</param>
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)
    {
      if (value == null)
        return true;
      for (int index = 0; index < value.Length; ++index)
      {
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(value[index]))
          return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: So this means `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is true for `string.Empty` as well! That's a bonus :)

Comment: yes , Safest will be to use IsNullOrWhiteSpace ( True for String.empty , null and whitespace )

Comment: @ΕГИІИО It's not a "bonus", it's what the function is specified to do ... and it would be nuts for it to return true on " " but not "" -- the whole point is to determine whether the string contains non-space characters. Of course, the name is therefore misleading.

Comment: @JimBalter When you have two methods IsNullOrEmpty() & IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), I don't know about you, but for me the later means it should return false on "" :) Definitely not the best naming, I'll give you that.

Comment: The "meaning" of a method is determined by its specification, not its name. A method that returned true for null or " " but false for "" would be useless, so the specification is good but--as we agree--the name is poor.

Answer (score 8):

It says it all `IsNullOrEmpty()` does not include white spacing while `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` does!

`IsNullOrEmpty()` If string is:
-Null
-Empty

`IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` If string is:
-Null
-Empty
-Contains White Spaces Only

Comment: I downvoted because while you explain what each function does, you don't answer the actual question.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include the whole list for "white space", as defined by he framework: The term “white space” includes all characters that are not visible on screen. For example, space, line break, tab and empty string are white space characters.

Comment: @tuespetre That is distressingly common at SO, and most of the another "answers" on this page are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful of escaped characters:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(""); //True
String.IsNullOrEmpty(null); //True
String.IsNullOrEmpty("   "); //False
String.IsNullOrEmpty("\n"); //False
String.IsNullOrEmpty("\t"); //False
String.IsNullOrEmpty("hello"); //False
```

and here:

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("");//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(null);//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("   ");//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\n");//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\t");//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("hello");//False
```

If you apply Trim to the values passed to IsNullOrEmpty(), the results for the two methods will be the same.

As a matter of performance, IsNullOrWhiteSpace() would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out with IsNullOrEmpty and IsNullOrwhiteSpace

```
string sTestes = "I like sweat peaches";
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 500; z++)
        {
            var x = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sTestes);// OR string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace
        }
    }

    stopWatch.Stop();
    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

You'll see that IsNullOrWhiteSpace is much slower :/

Comment: This is obvious because IsNullOrEmpty happens in constant time O(1)while IsNullOrwhiteSpace possibly requires a full iteration of the string or O(n) time.  Then your timed example is actually using nearly O(n^2) time.  For a one-timer with a normal-sized string, the performance difference is going to be negligible. If you were processing very large amounts of text or calling it in a large loop, then you probably wouldn't want to use it.

Comment: Of course it's slower, but that doesn't address the question.

Comment: @CharlesOwen "I like sweat peaches" is a "normal-sized" string, and the big-O of the function isn't changed by running it in a loop--that simply multiplies the times by a fixed factor (and irons out minor variations). If `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is "much slower" then it is poorly implemented, since it should return false upon examining the first character of `sTestes`. A properly implemented version is O(s) where s is the number of initial spaces in the string.

Answer (score 2):

In the .Net standard 2.0:

> `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`: Indicates whether the specified string is null or an Empty string.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(null));           // True
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(""));             // True
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(" "));            // False
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty("  "));           // False
```

> `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`: Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(null));     // True
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(""));       // True
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(" "));      // True
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("  "));     // True
```

Answer (score 1):

string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) - if you'd like to check string value has been provided

string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) - basically this is already a sort of business logic implementation (i.e. why "  " is bad, but something like "~~" is good).

My advice - do not mix business logic with technical checks.
So, for example, string.IsNullOrEmpty is the best to use at the beginning of methods to check their input parameters.

Answer (score -2):

What about this for a catch all...

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Trim())
{
}
```

This will trim all the spaces if they are there avoiding the performance penalty of IsWhiteSpace, which will enable the string to meet the "empty" condition if its not null.

I also think this is clearer and its generally good practise to trim strings anyway especially if you are putting them into a database or something.

Comment: This checking has a severe drawback. Calling Trim() on x will result a null reference exception when it is passed as null.

Comment: Good point. Ill leave the answer incorrect to show the drawback.

Comment: IsNullOrWhitespace MAY optimise to check for null or empty, avoiding checking the string for white space. This method will always perform the trimming operation. Also, though it might be optimised away, it will probably create another string in memory.

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x?.Trim()) should get around the null issue

Comment: I found exactly this bug in production code. In multiple places. It would be very funny if it weren't so sad.

Comment: What about it? It has nothing to do with the question, but is simply a terrible implementation of what IsNullOrWhiteSpace is supposed to do. "I'll leave the answer incorrect to show the drawback" -- that's not how SO works ... that information should be contained in the answer itself, not in the comments. But then, explaining one of the ways in which this is a bad answer would be yet another reason to delete it.