# string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.Trim()) vs string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

`string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.Trim())` vs `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString)`

Which one is faster or more reliable and why is that?

Comment: Complete guess (backed up by nothing), I'd say IsNullOrWhiteSpace.

Comment: Does it even matter? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Also, define "Reliable" in this context.

Comment: Interesting; I went to take a look at this in Reflector, and `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` doesn't show up in the `String` namespace the way one would expect from the MSDN documentation.  I wonder why that is.

Comment: @YYY Because it was introduced later, in the .NET Framework v4.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [string.IsNullOrEmpty(string) vs. string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976597/string-isnulloremptystring-vs-string-isnullorwhitespacestring)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.Trim())` will throw exception if `myString` is `null`, whereas `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString)` will work just fine, so it's more reliable.

As for the performance, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` should be faster.

`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString)` is prefered way of checking if variable is empty or whitespace.

Comment: Then I would like to ask ```string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.Trim())``` vs ```string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString?.Trim())```

Comment: Now you can do `string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString?.Trim())` so it does not =)

Answer (score 3):

> [**IsNullOrWhiteSpace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) is a convenience method that is similar to
>   the following code, except that it offers superior performance:

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0;
```

The only difference in reliability is that `myString.Trim()` may throw a [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx).

From a performance standpoint, [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) is the deciding factor. Notice how in the case of [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) the string is iterated through from each end. This can be especially costly in some cases, as @Lukazoid noted. [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) will start from the beginning and only iterate through the string until a non-whitespace character is found. Below is the .NET source.

```
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(String value) { 
        return (value == null || value.Length == 0); 
    }

    [Pure]
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
        if (value == null) return true;

        for(int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
            if(!Char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i])) return false; 
        } 

        return true; 
    }

    // Trims the whitespace from both ends of the string.  Whitespace is defined by
    // Char.IsWhiteSpace. 
    // 
    [Pure]
    public String Trim() { 
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        return TrimHelper(TrimBoth); 
    }

    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    private String TrimHelper(int trimType) { 
        //end will point to the first non-trimmed character on the right
        //start will point to the first non-trimmed character on the Left
        int end = this.Length-1;
        int start=0; 

        //Trim specified characters. 
        if (trimType !=TrimTail)  { 
            for (start=0; start < this.Length; start++) {
                if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(this[start])) break; 
            }
        }

        if (trimType !=TrimHead) { 
            for (end= Length -1; end >= start;  end--) {
                if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(this[end])) break; 
            } 
        }

        return CreateTrimmedString(start, end);
    }
```

Comment: You access to Microsoft.NET framework source code through the Reference Source website [http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString) is more reliable because it will not raise a NullReferenceException when myString is null.
I believe that IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString) is faster than myString.Trim(), think of a string containing 1 space in both ends and three million other chars in the middle.  These three million chars would have to be copied to a new string before checking.  IsNullOrWhiteSpace would have to compare two chars.

Answer (score 1):

`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` will be both more reliable and faster.

More reliable because it correctly handles null. And faster because it doesn't need to create a new string.

Comment: [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/isnullorwhitespace) it says `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is slower.

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` *is* slower than `IsNullOrEmpty()`. However, the original question was comparing it against `string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.Trim())`. Calling `Trim()` must create a new string and copy characters from the original string before it is tested. Altogether, I am quite sure `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go this far in terms of optimization, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString)` will have better performance as it is able to return a result immediately.

Take the following string:

```
" B C    " (4 trailing spaces)
```

With `string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.Trim())`:

1. Trim the string, iterating over 5 characters (1 preceeding and 4 trailing spaces), resulting in "B C"
2. IsNullOrEmpty iterates 1 character and returns false.

Total of 6 characters checked.

With `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(myString)`:

1. Iterate over 2 characters, returns false on the second character

Total of 2 characters checked.

The larger the number of trailing spaces, the bigger the benefits `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(myString)` will provide over the alternative.

As states in other answers and comments, the instantiation of the additional string result from `Trim()` adds more overhead.

Comment: Trim() iterates from the start and then from the end. 

The real difference is that it has to instantiate a new string

Comment: @Tar I did not think of that, thanks for informing me, I should have used reflector really. I'll update my answer to incorporate this knowledge

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application but you must be careful of escaped characters.
Here we considering `String.IsNullOrEmpty`:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(""); //True
String.IsNullOrEmpty(null); //True
String.IsNullOrEmpty("   "); //False
String.IsNullOrEmpty("\n"); //False
String.IsNullOrEmpty("\t"); //False
String.IsNullOrEmpty("hello"); //False
```

and now `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`:

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("");//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(null);//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("   ");//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\n");//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\t");//True
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("hello");//False
```

Comment: What if you aplly `Trim` to the values passed to `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, as OP does?

Comment: @GuruStron yes by applying Trim for String.IsNullOrEmpty, escaped characters will be empty and therefore two methods return the same results.