# How to check a text box is not null or empty

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net and I want to check a text box is not null or empty
I have used so many ways to find out
But none helped me out
These are the methods I have used

```
If textbox1.text.trim.Length >0 then
My sql insert query
End if

If textbox1.text<>"" then
End if
```

Could you help me out where I am going wrong

Comment: I would normally use `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) Then` - In what ways did your previous efforts fail?

Comment: @SteGriffiths thank you it worked.
I tried the code which I have  mentioned in the question but it keep on putting the null values in database . Your code helped me out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Trim` - for removing white spaces - there is another method which will fit your requirements:

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only
>   of white-space characters

```
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text) = False Then
    ' your MySql query
End
```

Actually both of your approaches should work too.
In Winforms `textBox.Text` will never be `null`, so checking for `.Length` after trimming should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them:

**1 :-  String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString);**

**1 :-  sNullOrWhiteSpace(yourString);**

For more details visit the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976597/string-isnulloremptystring-vs-string-isnullorwhitespacestring)

Comment: @user9396509 try this solution, i am hopeful this will work for you

Comment: thanks alot it worked fine