# Add returned user input to list of strings

Tags: c#, list, return-type

I'm working on a project that use different methods to get input from the user and I want to add the user input to a list.

My code looks like this:

```
public string GetValidName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Let's get you registered!");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your full name: ");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        bool validString = false;
        while (validString != true)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid input.");
                validString = false;
            }
            else
            {
                validString = true;
            }
        }

        return input;
    }
```

The list exists in the same class and is declared `public List<string> students = new();`

I have tried `return students.Add(input);` but that is not possible and gives the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

**Edit** This method is called through this method and has been edited with changes so it now looks like this;

```
    public void Register()
    {
        students.Add(GetValidName());
    }
```

To print all items in the list I use this piece of code:

```
    public void AttendenceList()
    {
        Students list = new();

        Console.WriteLine("All students attending class today:\r\n");
        foreach (var item in list.students)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

When the foreach loop runs, it only prints the Console.WriteLine though, and not any items in the list.

Comment: What exactly do you want to return from your method? The error message is because `List<string.Add(...)` does not return a value, hence `void`. Perhaps you meant to first add to the list, then `return input;` ?

Comment: btw. If you use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and the user enters only spaces it will return true as well. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976597/string-isnulloremptystring-vs-string-isnullorwhitespacestring)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I want to return the name that the user types in to keep track of which users are in school. So basically I want the users input in the list and I also have a foreach loop to print all values inside the list.

Comment: @JochemVanHespen Thank you, I did not think of this and will make changes in my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do `Students list = new();` you reintialize your list dont do that.

Like your list students is defined in the class, you could write:

```
public void AttendenceList()
{
    Console.WriteLine("All students attending class today:\r\n");
    foreach (var item in students)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when the method is called, I call it using `students.Add(GetValidName))` ?

Comment: no you write students.Add(GetValidName)) and not students.Add(GetValidName())

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I get another error saying "Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Comment: you do a typo in your precedent comment..  you write GetValidName  and not GetValidName()....so if its not the problem i suggest you to show your complete code with the call of the function and the definition of your list

Comment: i noticed, I have updated my original post with more information. The code gives no errors when typing it like you said in my `Register()`but won't show up when trying to print the items in list.

Comment: you create a new list! dont do that

Comment: yeah thanks for your help! I removed that code that created a new list and changed the placement of my list and it now works as I intended!